# How can I use maxNativeZoom with Leaflet.VectorGrid?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a tile set that is defined for zoom levels 0-2, but I want it to continue to show beyond a zoom level of 2. I believe this is done using maxNativeZoom however this setting doesnt seem to work, as the tiles are hidden beyond a zoom level of 2. How can I continue to show the vector tile set beyond a zoom level of 2, by stretching the tiles?

The full code for this problem is:

```js
var map = L.map('map');

// add openstreetmap basemap
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

const URL = 'https://gfswindtiles.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
const interpolator = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 4, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28].map(x => x * 1.94384))
    .range(["hsl(0, 0%, 100%)", "hsl(202, 88%, 51%)", "hsl(157, 96%, 53%)", "hsl(60, 100%, 49%)", "hsl(26, 100%, 49%)", "hsl(0, 64%, 43%)", "hsl(274, 47%, 29%)"]);

const opacityInterpolaotr = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 4, 12, 28].map(x => x * 1.94384))
    .range([0, 0, 1, 1]);

const vectorStyle = {
    wind: function (properties, zoom) {
        var speed = properties.wind_speed_max;
        const color = interpolator(speed);
        const opacity = opacityInterpolaotr(speed);
        return {
            fill: true,
            fillColor: color,
            stroke: false,
            fillOpacity: opacity
        };
    }
};

L.vectorGrid.protobuf(URL, {
    rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
    // token: TOKEN,
    vectorTileLayerStyles: vectorStyle,
    maxNativeZoom: 20,
    maxZoom: 2
}).addTo(map);

map.setView({
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
}, 3);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#map {
    background: #F9F7F7;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@latest/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id='map' style='width: 100vw; height: 100vh'></div>
</body>
```

To see the effect, press zoom out to show the vector tile set and then zoom in again to show it disappearing

Comment: Swap maxNativeZoom and maxZoom. maxZoom - max zoom level you want to display data, maxNativeZoom - max zoom level provided from tile server. You should have maxNativeZoom: 2, maxZoom: 20